# Laravel css and JS resources loading twice per page load?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am running into some strange issue where per page load multiple css/js resources are loading twice. Cache is cleared. not sure what is going on? happening on my dev environment and live environment.

When you view the source of the page obviously they are only on their once - however the network tab is showing them load over and over and with the app.js file being a monster it causes latency issues obviously.

[image]

anyone else run into this issue or know what could be causing this?

Headsection:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
<!-- Google Font -->
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
<title>Title</title>

<!-- CSRF Token -->
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="{{ asset('css/sticky-footer-navbar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ asset('css/jPushMenu.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

FooterJS:

```
 <!-- Scripts -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Citti

Comment: please post your html here including the header

Comment: is it loading twice or just continually loading the file? i take it you are not compiling the assets?

Comment: Will also add when i remove the bootstrap line or app.js the page will not load the file at all (or i guess both times) but as soon as i put it back into the template it loads twice...

Comment: Your header and footer seems good to me.. Please post the whole html page

Comment: @ShadyAtef I have litterally removed everything from the body. Just loading a blank page and it does the same thing. so what you see here is what i am loading. except for the </head> and <body> tags...

Comment: @upful would it matter if I compiled the assets at any point? would that make it load twice?

Comment: @citti no I was just observing that you weren't using the [built in compiler](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) ... I would say look in custom.css and app.js for something referencing bootstrap.min.css

Comment: so i took out the integrity and cross orgin tag on the bootstrap min which seemed to help their.

Comment: app.js now just seems to load once and then load again after the page is completed loading...