# My Application is Loading CSS files twice?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vite, inertiajs

I accidentally noticed that my website is loading the same CSS file twice.

I use Laravel with Inertia, Vue, and Vite.

This cache postfix, `23c49378`, is appearing twice.

[image]

If I look in the Networks tab, it only appears once, which means it's only fetched once, which is good. However, if I look at the Elements, they have the same styles applied twice.

[image]

**app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
@if(Route::is('admin.*'))
  @php($__inertiaSsrDispatched = true)
  @php($__inertiaSsrResponse = null)
@endif

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="{{Cookie::get('theme') === 'dark' ? '#1f2937' : '#FFFFFF'}}" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#2b5797">

  <link rel="canonical" href="{{ $canonical }}"  />
  @if(Route::current())
    <link rel="alternate" hreflang="x-default" href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), array_merge(Route::current()->parameters(), ['locale' => 'en'])) }}" />

    @if(isset($locales) && Route::current() !== null)
      @foreach($locales as $locale)
        <link rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $locale }}" href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), array_merge(Route::current()->parameters(), ['locale' => $locale])) }}" />
      @endforeach
    @endif
  @endif

  <!-- Scripts -->
  @routes(nonce: Vite::cspNonce())

  @if(Route::is('admin.*'))
    @vite(['resources/js/admin.ts', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
  @else
    @vite(['resources/js/app.ts', "resources/js/Pages/App/{$page['component']}.vue"])
  @endif
  
  @inertiaHead

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-SDK4391YJ7" defer async nonce="{{ Vite::cspNonce() }}"></script>
  <script defer nonce="{{ Vite::cspNonce() }}">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){window.dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'G-SDK4391YJ7');
  </script>
</head>

<body class="font-sans overflow-y-scroll antialiased @if(Cookie::get('theme') === 'dark') {{'dark'}} @endif @if (Cookie::get('expansion') == 'deflated') {{Cookie::get('expansion')}} @endif bg-white dark:bg-black">
  @inertia
</body>
</html>
```

**app.ts**

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';

import {InertiaProgress} from '@inertiajs/progress';
import {resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';

import {Ziggy} from './ziggy';
import {ZiggyVue} from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

createInertiaApp({
  title: (title) => `${title}`,
  // @ts-ignore
  resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/App/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/App/**/*.vue')),
  // @ts-ignore
  setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
    //const application = createSSRApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
    const application = createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
      .use(plugin)
      .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
      .mount(el)
    return application;
  },
})
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/js'),
      '@ziggy': path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/js/ziggy')
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    laravel({
      input: {
        main: 'resources/js/app.ts',
        admin: 'resources/js/admin.ts',
      },
      ssr: 'resources/js/ssr.ts',
      refresh: true,
    }),
    vue({
      reactivityTransform: true,
      template: {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          base: null,
          includeAbsolute: false,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  ssr: {
    noExternal: [
      '@inertiajs/server'
    ],
  },
});
```

I'm a bit confused as to where to start... It looks like it's being done as part of the inertia insertions?

Comment: start by removing code. Keep removing `link` elements until one of the duplicates disappears. If you've removed all `link` elements and you still have duplicates, start removing vue blocks until one of the two disappears. You've now found (one of the two) places where you're injecting that stylesheet.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, its being iserted automatically by inertia, i dont create the link elements mysself

Comment: Your `app.blade.php` file has a _huge_ head element, and step one in debugging is always "remove everything not related to the problem" (explained in more detail over in the [mcve] article), so you still want to go through that and empty out that head element. Worst case you end up with duplicates despite having emptied the head entirely: now you have less code left to look at.

Comment: I know about the practices Mike, thanks for pointing out.. as they say, its not that big, and I find the head section relevant, all of it.

Comment: I'm not saying to delete it in your actual codebase: you're debugging right now. Branch off, start removing code, and then once you've found the problem, throw away the branch and fix things in your real code.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the question to make it a little less messy for the purpose of this debugging

Comment: Show also your `vite.config.js`

Comment: @Styx  Sure, i will do that when I get home from work :)

Comment: Is this happening only in development or also in production?

Comment: @Kalimah both production and development

Comment: see the comments in this other post, they fixed it by removing some bootstrap tags https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726586/laravel-css-and-js-resources-loading-twice-per-page-load

Comment: Why do you pass both the application entry file (admin.ts or app.ts - this is fine) WITH a Vue file (this is questionable if necessary) in the @vite directive?

Comment: @juanmajmjr unfortunately did that not do much for my application, I'm thinking about just installing a new project when laravel 11 is release, and move my stuff into that repo.... i simply cant figure out why its doing it... its happening in the inertiahead

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the app.ts file, for some reason if i remove the css import from app.ts it does not load it twice.

Answer (score 0):

#### Declare Problem

I don't understand why you're loading the `admin.ts` and a Vue file, as well as `app.ts` and another Vue file.

```php
@if(Route::is('admin.*'))
  @vite(['resources/js/admin.ts', "resources/js/Pages/{$page['component']}.vue"])
@else
  @vite(['resources/js/app.ts', "resources/js/Pages/App/{$page['component']}.vue"])
@endif
```

#### Correct Usage

```php
@if(Route::is('admin.*'))
  @vite(['resources/js/admin.ts'])
@else
  @vite(['resources/js/app.ts'])
@endif
```

Load either `admin.ts` or `app.ts` depending on the path, that's correct. Let's forget about the Vue files. If you're using Inertia, the task is to specify on the server side which layout you want to load at the given route.

```php
return Inertia::render('name-of-vue-file');
```

Now, `admin.ts` or `app.ts` can use `'name-of-vue-file'`, when create inertia frontend app:

```js
resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/App/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/App/**/*.vue')),
```

Here, name will `'name-of-vue-file'`, so will loaded `./Pages/App/name-of-vue-file.vue`.

For every route whose responsibility is rendering, it should return with `Inertia::render`, where you specify this filename.

#### Source

- [Server Side Setup](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup) - InertiaJS Docs
- [Client Side Setup](https://inertiajs.com/client-side-setup) - InertiaJS Docs

After all, the essence of InertiaJS is that your frontend application can be JavaScript-based, yet you can maintain the convenience of issuing server-side instructions to determine which page you want to view. If this is not what you need, you can create a separate Laravel API application and a separate Vue application, between which you can communicate via an API.

Comment: I see, it works perfectly fine doing the "correct usage", however, my application still loads 2 CSS files.

It is like the CSS file is being included by two instances, and the first 5 files are being included above my GoogleTag Manager Snippet, some preload, AND the main CSS file.

Then after the Google Tag manager snippet all of the modules AND the CSS file are included.